# MathJax: do not show raw latex preview

Tags: mathjax

If you visit a page with MathJax on it, you will see raw latex for a moment, before is is processed and turned into nice "math". Is it possible to not show that raw source, and only display the math once it is ready?

Example page: http://www.mathjax.org/demos/tex-samples/

Comment: Saw this question linked in another post. I answered there if you're still interested to know, there might be a way to do this using the config method: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43012299/1184361

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what you mean by that. Naturally, what's in the page will be displayed and if you rely on JS to remove it then there's always a chance it will be visible for a minimal amount.

The straight-forward approach is to hide your content and tell MathJax to unhide it once typesetting is done. (This will depend on the complexity of your content and your design.)

[This sample](http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/test/sample-all-at-once.html) (which can be found [in the main code repository](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/blob/master/test/sample-all-at-once.html)) shows as simple approach:

a) set `visibility:hidden` on some global element

b)  Add a function to the MathJax queue to change it back once MathJax layout is done. E.g.,

```
 <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(function () {
       document.getElementById("hide_page").style.visibility = "";
    });
 </script>
```