# How do I prevent MathJax from showing raw TeX while waiting for rendering to complete?

Tags: mathjax

I have some MathJax on my webpage and would like *nothing* to appear until the MathJax has finished processing my equations: no raw *LaTeX* and no loading progress indicator.

Is there a way to accomplish this with MathJax configuration settings?

Comment: How about adding a class to the math divs that hides them, then remove the class when MathJax completes.

Comment: @StephenThomas: That's one approach (for the equations at least, but not the progress message). How do I detect when MathJax completes?

Comment: There's a callback. Check the documentation

Comment: There is [an example](http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/test/sample-all-at-once.html) that does what you ask in the MathJax test directory

Comment: @DavideCervone: Thanks. That still shows the status/progress thingy.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius, yes that example is set up to allow the progress message.  If you want to hide absolutely everything, move the `hide_page` id and the initial style to the body element.  Or you could set `messageStyle:"none"` in your MathJax configuration.

Comment: Have you find any solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

Hey if you still need an answer, try the following.

If you call `MathJax.Hub.Config()`, pass the parameter `preview: "none"` to the `tex2jax` object in the config. Like so:

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({

   tex2jax:
   {
      preview: "none"
   }

});
```

This will not show any raw tex commands that MathJax will pick up. It will allow to you still display other elements in your markup so your page doesn't look blank as the browser renders it.

Hope this helps.